# InvalidFieldFormat when obtaining token from intuit quickbooks

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

When I try to call:

POST /oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer?grant_type=authorization_code&code=XXX&redirect_uri=https://developer.intuit.com/v2/OAuth2Playground/RedirectUrl

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic XXX
I get Status: 400 Code: InvalidFieldFormat Type:SYSTEM from every platform (curl, postman, mongodb stitch). The only place where it works is the intuit playground.
I do not see what is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pass everything via a query string, and you should be passing it in the `POST` body.

You should be `POST`ing to this URL: `https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer`

And passing in a HTTP request body like this:

```
grant_type=authorization_code&
code=L3114709614564VSU8JSEiPkXx1xhV8D9mv4xbv6sZJycibMUI&
redirect_uri=https://www.mydemoapp.com/oauth-redirect
```

It's the `POST` body, not the query string.

This is documented on Intuit's site here: 
https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0#step-5-exchange-authorization-code-for-refresh-and-access-tokens